# Iphone to Ipad porting-only top left usable

Tags: iphone, ipad, porting

So I'm trying to port an existing iphone application to the ipad. When I run the targeted device set to ipad, only the top left corner of the screen is usable, (the size of the iphone). However, all table cells, objects and buttons exted out to the width of the ipad. But that area is not responsive. What am I doing wrong?

I also tried autoresizing some of the views, and even doing "upgrade current target for ipad," and selecting "two devices," though I don't know what it does. Upgrading it adds a new target, but doesn't change anything

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653761/ipad-touch-detected-only-in-320x480-region

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, it's because we didn't enable full screen.