# iPad touches only registering within 320x480 boundary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, cocoa-touch

(This question is similar to: [iPad touch detected only in 320x480 region](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653761/ipad-touch-detected-only-in-320x480-region), but that question's answers are from 2010 and are outdated)

In my app, I am adding iPad support, and the app works fine in ViewController_iPad.xib, but when I add another class in like so:

(objMainMenu is a property of ViewController)

```
//iPhone
if (objMainMenu == nil && UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    objMainMenu = [[MainMenuClass alloc] initWithNibName: @"MainMenuClass"  bundle:nil];
//iPad
if (objMainMenu == nil && UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    objMainMenu = [[MainMenuClass alloc] initWithNibName: @"MainMenuClass_iPad" bundle:nil];

objMainMenu.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview: objMainMenu.view];
```

...it only registers touches within the 320 x 480 boundary. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The answers in the question you linked are not outdated just because they're old. Setting "Full Screen at Launch" on your window should work.

Comment: How do I actually do that? There's no MainWindow.xib anymore, and self.window.fullScreenAtLaunch (or similar) doesn't exist

Comment: Try adding `self.window.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];` in your AppDelegate's `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`